# How to make ProgressIndicator to fade out?

Tags: animation, windows-phone-8, fadeout, progress-indicator

In my WP8 application I use a `ProgressIndicator` and I'd like it to fade out before making it invisible. I can't find any documentation describing how I can do that, the only exposed property of `ProgressIndicator` is `IsVisible` which does not provide any animation.

Yet in some applications I can clearly see progress bar fading out.
So how can I make it fade out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't animate the Shell components of WP7/WP8 beyond their default animations. As ProgressIndicator & SystemTray are part of the Shell UI (alongside with ApplicationBar, MessageBox and others) you'll have to settle for the buit-in transitions.

If this really troubles you, you can always recreate the ProgressIndicator exprience with a managed ProgressBar as part of your app's `<Frame />` Template.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [DoubleAnimation class on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimation
          Storyboard.TargetName="MyProgressBar"
          Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
          From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:5" 
          Completed="DisableMyProgressBar"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <ProgressBar x:Name="MyProgressBar"  />

</StackPanel>
```

In the code behind trigger the animation when your processing is complete.

```
private void StopProgressBar()
{
     myStoryboard.Begin();
}
```

You will want to disable the progress bar and reset its opacity after it fades out, so use the Completed event of the Storyboard to reset these properties.

[Timeline.Completed on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

```
private void DisableMyProgressBar(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyProgressBar.IsEnabled = false;
    MyProgressBar.Opacity = 1;
}
```